# Best practices when connecting to AWS RDS with Lambda + pymysql?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora, pymysql

I'm trying to create a setup with AWS where users can hit an API endpoint -> Lambda function connects to Aurora serverless DB.

This guide https://levelup.gitconnected.com/aws-lambda-with-rds-using-pymysql-23ad3cde46c8 is suggesting I put

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host,user=name,passwd=password,db=db_name,...)
```

at the start of the lambda function. My worry is that every API request will create a new connection to the database, not sure if that is ok? I know that when locally performing operations, there is such a thing as creating a connection pool. Is there a recommendation on how/when this is needed on AWS Lambda?

Comment: You can use RDS proxy to keep those connections alive.

Answer (score 0):

Please review article below to Demystifying Lambda functionality and how handle the request executions

https://harishkm.in/2020/06/30/demystifying-database-connection-pools-in-aws-lambda-functions/

Also links below explain you how AWS Aurora handles the connection

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/amazon-aurora-mysql-db-admin-handbook/connection-management-and-pooling.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/amazon-aurora-mysql-db-admin-handbook/connection-handling-in-aurora-mysql-and-mysql.html

Regarding pymysql, you could use boto3 AWS SDK library instead of pymysql, it provides you better integration with AWS Services like AWS Lambda,AWS IAM and AWS Secret Manager as best practices

```
import boto3
rds_client = boto3.client('rds-data')
```

Review link below.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-the-data-api-to-interact-with-an-amazon-aurora-serverless-mysql-database/

Finally if your API traffic will be high, consider use scalable solutions as AWS RDS Proxy to help you to manage your database connection at scale, review links below.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scale-modern-serverless-applications-with-amazon-rds-proxy-for-sql-server/

Comment: The `rds-data` API only works with Aurora Serverless V1 at this time.